# How to use multicols and equal rows on each column?

Tags: enumerate, multicol

I'm trying to arrange these in rows of 5's but because the integers take up less space, I get 3 items on one column instead of 2 each.

Is there something I can do without doing tables? Like a multirows thing?

```
\begin{multicols}{5}
    \begin{enumerate}
       \item \(5\cfrac{1}{2}\)
       \item \(2\cfrac{1}{4}\)
       \item 1
       \item 8
       \item 4
       \item \(1\cfrac{7}{8}\)
       \item \(2\cfrac{5}{6}\)
       \item \(3\cfrac{5}{6}\)
       \item \(7\cfrac{2}{5}\)
       \item \(4\cfrac{2}{9}\)
     \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
```

Comment: Please, give us a MWE.

Comment: `\cfrac` is designed for continued fractions in display mode so produces the bad spacing here, the correct markup would be `\frac` as shown in the third of Werner's examples in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To maintain a consistent high for "vertically challenged" `\item`s, add an appropriately-sized `\vphantom`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{5}
  \begin{enumerate}
   \item $5\cfrac{1}{2}$
   \item $2\cfrac{1}{4}$
   \item $1\vphantom{\cfrac{1}{2}}$
   \item $8\vphantom{\cfrac{1}{2}}$
   \item $4\vphantom{\cfrac{1}{2}}$
   \item $1\cfrac{7}{8}$
   \item $2\cfrac{5}{6}$
   \item $3\cfrac{5}{6}$
   \item $7\cfrac{2}{5}$
   \item $4\cfrac{2}{9}$
   \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\noindent\hrulefill

\begin{multicols}{5}
  \begin{enumerate}
   \item $5\dfrac{1}{2}$
   \item $2\dfrac{1}{4}$
   \item $1\vphantom{\dfrac{1}{1}}$
   \item $8\vphantom{\dfrac{1}{1}}$
   \item $4\vphantom{\dfrac{1}{1}}$
   \item $1\dfrac{7}{8}$
   \item $2\dfrac{5}{6}$
   \item $3\dfrac{5}{6}$
   \item $7\dfrac{2}{5}$
   \item $4\dfrac{2}{9}$
   \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\noindent\hrulefill

\begin{multicols}{5}
  \begin{enumerate}
   \item $5\frac{1}{2}$
   \item $2\frac{1}{4}$
   \item $1$
   \item $8$
   \item $4$
   \item $1\frac{7}{8}$
   \item $2\frac{5}{6}$
   \item $3\frac{5}{6}$
   \item $7\frac{2}{5}$
   \item $4\frac{2}{9}$
   \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

I'd go with using `\frac` only as it sets a `t`ext-sized `\tfrac` rather than `d`isplay-sized `\dfrac` (or a `c`ontinued `\cfrac`).